# Send E-mail on submitting form to Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a website to take bookings using a html form and submit the form to firestore, also as soon as the data is submitted an confirmation mail is send to the customer. I am using the code given below to achieve it.

```
var firestore = firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("bookingData");

//listen for submit
document.getElementById("bookingForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //get values
  var email = getInputVal("email");
  var packageFields = getInputVal("packageFields");
  var name = getInputVal("name");
  var phone = getInputVal("phone");
  var date = getInputVal("date");
  var [persons] = getInputVal("persons");

  saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date, persons);
  sendEmail(email, packageFields, name, date, persons);
  //show alert
}

// function to get form values

function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date, persons) {
  messagesRef
    .add({
      email: email,
      packageFields: packageFields,
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      date: date,
      persons: persons,
    })
    .then(function (docRef) {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      console.log(email);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
}

function sendEmail(packageFields, name, date, persons) {
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    To: "subhodiproy161101@gmail.com",
    From: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
    Body: `Your package of ${packageFields} for ${name} with total ${persons} persons (incl. ${name}) dated ${date} has been provisonalised. Your seat will be confirmed once you complete the payment of the Security Deposit`,
  }).then(function (message) {
    alert("mail sent successfully");
  });
}
```

Everything is working fine but the `email id` of the `To:` is constant, I would like to change the `To:` field automatically based on the email id given in the form, How can I do So?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new argument of your `sendMail` function the `email` and pass it to `To:`:

```
function sendEmail(email, packageFields, name, date, persons) {
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    To: email,
    From: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
    Body: `Your package of ${packageFields} for ${name} with total ${persons} persons (incl. ${name}) dated ${date} has been provisonalised. Your seat will be confirmed once you complete the payment of the Security Deposit`,
  }).then(function (message) {
    alert("mail sent successfully");
  });
}
```